# Make an installer for IE and firefox addons

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, firefox-addon, xpi

I want to pack the xpi file into my IE addons installer.
The IE addons installer is created by VS2010

I am no idea how to make a setup file for XPI (firefox addons)
My addon is a toolbar.